# Connect to database over internet

Tags: sql-server, database

I'd like to connect to my MS SQL database hosted on another computer over internet.
What I did:

-> I'm using NO-IP (dynamic DNS)

-> I created SQL Authentication Account and I can connect to it from local computer using MSSMS like this:
**Server name:** local_ip\SQLEXPRESS **Login:** ###, **Password:** ###

-> I disabled firewall

-> I set port in SQL Server Configuration Manager (to 49XXX) and forwarded this port AND 1434 in router settings to my computer

-> SQL Server Browser is running

Now I'd like to connect to this DB from another computer (different network): **Server name:** tcp:my_no_ip_name.ddns.net,49XX **Login:** ###, **Password:** ###

I can't connect. All the time I get "Cannot connect to my_no_ip_name.ddns.net"

Am I missing something?

Comment: "disabled firewall". Well, there's something that's going to show up in a report on why you got hacked.

Comment: Try out http://canyouseeme.org to see if your service si accsessible. Enter your ip and the port you are running MySQL on.

Comment: According this website I can't even access port 80

Comment: Is my Server name valid?  or should I use different format?

Comment: Would this be a question better asked at serverfault?

Answer (score 0):

on local ssms, try to connect as yourserver.ddns.net,portnumber\instancename.  windows authentication doesnt work on mine but ok with sql server authentication (try to avoid using sa account).  dont forget to port forward on the router and open port in sql server firewall.  Leave the ports on default (1433) in config manager.  Not the most secure but once it works you can harden it by changing it to a non-default port and using a more secure user id in sql server logins which only has access to the database you want...